# In VSCode, right click and select "Run Jest" returns error "The system cannot find the path specified."

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, jestjs

this has been doing my head in most of the evening.

In VSCode, inside a .test.tsx file, I right click and select "Run Jest" and I get returned the error "The system cannot find the path specified."

This does not happen when running all tests from npm scripts within package.json file.

Using Windows 10, VSCode v 1.41.1, node 12.4.0

Any help appreciated.